# What is the probability of being dealt a 2-pair 5 hand consisting of EXACTLY two pairs of face cards? (A face card is a King, Queen and Jack)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have:
c(3,2) * c(3,2)
 [picking two pairs from a choice of 3 face values] . 
c(4,2)* c(4,2) 
[picking two suits from a choice of 4 suit values] . 
c(10,1) 
[not a face value for the 5th card] . 
c(4,1)
 [choose a suit for the 5th card] .

c(3,2) * c(3,2) * c(4,2)* c(4,2) * c(10,1) * c(4,1) / c(52,5)

Can someone please check my work and let me know of any errors? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

$\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose two distinct face values that will make up the two pairs.

$\binom{4}{2} \binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two suits for each pair.

$52-8$ ways to choose the fifth card. (It just has to be a value different from the two pairs, it's fine for it to be a third face value)

Comment: there cannot be a third face vaule.

Comment: @onlineuser Given the title of your question I disagree. But if you insist, then you'd just have to change my last expression to $52 - 12$ instead of $52-8$.

Comment: the title says EXACTLY two pairs of face cards not AT LEAST two pairs of face cards

Comment: @onlineuser If the fifth card is a different face card, the number of pairs of face cards that you have is still EXACTLY two (that is, I read "exactly" as modifying "number of pairs"). That said, I recognize that you are reading "exactly" as modifying "composition of face cards." There is some ambiguity here, so you may need to seek clarification about what is meant in your situation (homework, etc.).